# Key-Value RDD: Why same duplicates Value Tuples? (Scala)

Tags: scala, duplicates, tuples

I am very new to Scala and while builting an application I came across of this strange effect:

First let me give you some details:

I have a dataset witch I import into my application and do stuff. It is a csv in which each row has this form:

```
x : Double, y : Double, class : String
```

Each row of this dataset incudes the coordinates of a point and the class of this point.

My goal is, after some calculations, to calculate a new value based on this dataset and to create an RDD using the dataset given combined with a new column holding the new value, with a **key-value** pair.

The RDD would have as a **key** the coordinates, (x,y) of each point and as **value** the class AND the new value with the name icch_id : String!

The correct form for this RDD in my mind would include two tuples, which would be like this :

```
(x : Double, y : Double),(icch_id : String, class : String)
```

I reach a point in my application after some calculations where I have this RDD to work with :

**DATA_RDD :**

```
(icch_id : String, x : Double, y : Double, class : String)
```

A print of a part of this RDD is shown bellow:

```
//DATA_RDD print:
(ICCH_1,4.3,3.0,Iris-setosa)
(ICCH_1,4.4,2.9,Iris-setosa)
```

And I am writing this code to convert it to the key-value form I want which is the one I wrote above :

```
val DATA_RDD_Final  = DATA_RDD
      .keyBy{case (_, x, y, _) => (x, y)}
      .mapValues{ case (icch_id, _, _, pclass) => (icch_id,pclass) }
      .groupByKey()
```

**And at this point the problem begins.**

If I print the **DATA_RDD_Final** the result is :

```
//A part of the Result:
((5.4,3.0),CompactBuffer((ICCH_1,Iris-versicolor))) //Almost Correct!
((6.7,3.3),CompactBuffer((ICCH_3,Iris-virginica), (ICCH_3,Iris-virginica))) //Wrong!
```

**The problem:** Instead of a simple Tuple I get a CompactBuffer with exactly the same duplicates of the Value Tuple.

And I am asking:

1. Why this happens? Is it a code problem?
2. I am using databricks community edition. Does this affect something?
3. Is there a way, after I create the DATA_RDD_Final, to remove all duplicates and return the form I wanted from the start?

Thank you so much on behalf ans sorry for the long post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution!

The use of `.groupByKey()` creates the problem. When I remove it and I simply use `.collect()`

```
val Data_Array_Final  = Data_RDD
      .keyBy{case (_, x, y, _) => (x, y)}
      .mapValues{ case (id, _, _, pclass) => (id,pclass) }
      .collect()
```

Everything looks ok except one little drawback. Instead of an RDD, it returns an Array. So I needed to make:

```
val Data_RDD_Final = sc.parallelize(Data_Array_Final)
```

to get the result I wanted. Now I have an RDD of the correct form:

```
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[((Double, Double), (String, String))]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by using a single `map`:

```
rdd.map {
  case (id, x, y, pclass) => ((x, y), (id, pclass))
}
```

Comment: Would this create a key-value pair?

Comment: In `((x, y), (id, pclass))` `(x, y)` is the first element of the pair and `(id, pclass)` is the second. Just open the code in an IDE and make sure that all pair operations are available for this rdd.